# Could somebody review am I right in calculation of licenses for the Enterprise SP 2016 farm and Project Server below?

Tags: 2016, server-farm, licensing

Could somebody review am I right in calculation of licenses for the Enterprise SP 2016 farm and Project Server below?

### Target topology:

- Web Front End [Windows Server 2016] - 1
- Application + Distributed Cache [Windows Server 2016] - 1
- Search [Windows Server 2016] - 1
- Database / SQL Server 2016 [Windows Server 2016] - 1
- Office Web Apps [Windows Server 2016] - 1
- Development Standalone farm [Windows Server 2016] - 1

### The list of MS licenses:

`Server licenses`

- Microsoft Windows Server 2016 - 6 pcs
- SharePoint Server 2016 - 6 pcs
- SQL Server Enterprise 2016 - 6 pcs
- Project Server 2016 - 1 pcs

`Client Access Licensing`

- SharePoint 2016 Standard CAL - 135 pcs
- SharePoint 2016 Enterprise CAL - 135 pcs
- Project Server 2016 CAL - 100 pcs
- Windows Server 2016 CAL - 135 pcs

Questions:

>> Do we need the SQL Server CAL licenses for users?

Comment: why have you specified 135 pieces of CAL licenses, would you pelase explain this, I am trying to understand teh scenerio here.

Comment: Because 135 employees should have an access to the SharePoint and about 100 employees to Project.

Answer (score 1):

Please contact Microsoft regarding all licensing questions as there are so many uncertainties at this point on your list, e.g.,

- you will definitely NOT need SQL Server Enterprise license on all servers
- you might not even need SQL Ent, but might be fine with Std
- you don't need both Std and Ent CAL for SharePoint
- you don't need SP license on SQL Server, unless you use Reporting Services and install SP on SQL
- you don't need SP license on Office Web Apps, but may need Office CALs if you want people to be able to modify Office docs using browser
- you might not need SP license on Dev machine, if you have MSDN developer licenses